# Dart Native Extension inside Docker

Tags: docker, dart

Hi I'm using docker image from [google/dart-runtime](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/dart-runtime/) and use dependency

```
dependencies:
  sqlite:
    git: 
      url: https://github.com/putraxor/dart-sqlite
```

[dart-sqlite](https://github.com/putraxor/dart-sqlite) use native library [libdart_sqlite.so](https://github.com/putraxor/dart-sqlite/blob/master/lib/src/libdart_sqlite.so) but when I run it inside docker, it always complains `libdart_sqlite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directoryerror: library handler failed`

this is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM google/dart-runtime
USER root
RUN pub upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution
So basically libsqlite3 is not installed on Docker by default, it can be checked with command:

```
RUN ldd lib/src/libdart_sqlite.so
```

The solution:

```
FROM google/dart-runtime
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```